# Issue when scaling image using matrix in ImageView

Tags: android, matrix, resize, imageview, scale

I have the following snippet of code in the onCreate method of a class that extends Activity:

```
 ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.sample_landscape, bmpFactoryOptions);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "Display Width: " + display.getWidth());
Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "Display Height: " + display.getHeight());

Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "BMP Width: " + bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth);
Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "BMP Height: " + bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight);

if (bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth > width || bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight > height) {
    float heightRatio = (float) height / (float) bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight;
    float widthRatio = (float) width / (float) bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth;

    // WHY
    heightRatio = heightRatio / 1.5f;
    widthRatio = widthRatio / 1.5f;

    Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "heightRatio:" + heightRatio);
    Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "widthRatio: " + widthRatio);

    float scale = widthRatio;
    if (heightRatio < widthRatio) {
        scale = heightRatio;
    }

    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "Scale: " + scale);
} else {
    Log.v("IMAGEVIEWERMATRIX", "NOTNOTNOT");
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
}

Bitmap realBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.sample_landscape);
view.setImageBitmap(realBmp);
view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

When I run it, the image appears on screen scaled to fit correctly.  My issue is that I have to adjust the scale by 1.5 in order for this to be correct.

```
heightRatio = heightRatio / 1.5f;
widthRatio = widthRatio / 1.5f;
```

My intuition is that this has to do with the display density of the device but for the life of me, I can't wrap my head around why I would need to do this.

Here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:scaleType="matrix"     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question here.  The issue that I was seeing has to do with where I put the image asset.  I had it in the res/drawable-mdpi folder only and the device I was testing on was high density.  Therefore, Android was scaling the image up for me automagically. To rectify the situation and deal with the pixels directly, I placed the image in the res/drawable-nodpi folder.

This behavior is described on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html under "How Android supports multiple screens".